# Windows Server 2012 R2 under KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

Usually I deal with Linux and other Unix-like OS, but now I have to set up Windows server to run some specific software.

I can't have physical box for it, so I decide to buy and deploy Windows Server 2012 R2 on [KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) virtual machine.

Reading licensing documents on Microsoft website I cannot understand, what is the difference between "installation on physical server" and "installation on virtual machine" in WinServer terminology. I phoned Microsoft store support, but they also can't answer me, course they don't know what KVM is =)

So my first question is: when running under KVM, would Windows Server 2012 R2 "think" that it running under virtual, or physical environment?

The second is related - which type of licence ("for physical server installation" or "for VM installation") do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my first question is: when running under KVM, would Windows Server
>   2012 R2 "think" that it running under virtual, or physical
>   environment?

It does not matter what Windows "thinks" it is running under. It is running in a virtual machine, and that is what is important licensing-wise.